# Failed to get the Accelerometer readings on Kaa SandBox server

Tags: android, cassandra, apache-zeppelin, kaa

I have tried to send the **Accelerometer** data to Kaa sandbox and do some data analytics 
so I have created and activity to get the accelerometer sensor readings and I also created a Kaa manager to start the kaa client

**but I got this error**

> 03-06 17:10:42.117 2945-2978/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc I/*ultOperationTcpChannel: Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message
>       03-06 17:10:42.163 2945-2983/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc I/AbstractHttpChannel: Processing sync all for channel default_bootstrap_channel
>       03-06 17:10:42.178 2945-2980/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc
>       03-06 17:10:42.184 2945-2980/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc E/DefaultBootstrapChannel: Failed to receive operation servers list {}
>                                                                                               org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:9889 refused
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.transport.AndroidHttpClient.executeHttpRequest(AndroidHttpClient.java:112)
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.processTypes(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:56)
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.access$200(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:32)
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel$BootstrapRunnable.run(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:92)
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.transport.AndroidHttpClient.executeHttpRequest(AndroidHttpClient.java:112) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.processTypes(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:56) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.access$200(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:32) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel$BootstrapRunnable.run(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:92) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
>                                                                                                   at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:454)
>                                                                                                   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:136)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:379) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492) 
>                                                                                                   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.transport.AndroidHttpClient.executeHttpRequest(AndroidHttpClient.java:112) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.processTypes(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:56) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel.access$200(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:32) 
>                                                                                                   at org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel$BootstrapRunnable.run(DefaultBootstrapChannel.java:92) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>       03-06 17:10:42.185 2945-2980/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc I/DefaultFailoverManager: Server [BOOTSTRAP, -1835393002] failed
>       03-06 17:10:42.186 2945-2980/org.kaaproject.kaa.demo.testAcc W/DefaultChannelManager: Attempt to connect to the next bootstrap service will be made in 2000 ms, according to failover strategy decision

I have also tried to use the Cell monitor demo, bu I was not receiving anything on MongoDB. Also the source code was missing "`kaaManager.start(this);`" 
After adding this line I got the same error stated above

please help me to solve this issue

Thanks
Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue

1- Open Kaa Sandbox and navigate to
http://>>kaa-sandbox-IP-address<<:9080/sandbox/#management:

[Troubleshooting guide](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Troubleshooting+guide)

2- Update the Kaa host/IP with the machine host IP address

3- generate the SDK file for the requested platform

4- make sure you are not low disk space